# wordpress phonegap json doesnt work

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova

I'm reading a tutorial and I'm having some problems with the examples... I tried to run the examples but i dont have results:

**app.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<header>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/
jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function readSinglePost (url,target_div) {
var URL = url
jQuery.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery(target_div).html(data.post.content);
    }
});
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#title").html("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
var url = "http://www.recorramisiones.com.ar/api/get_post/? json=get_post&dev=1&p=934";
var target_div = "#contents";
readSinglePost(url, target_div);
});
</script>
</header>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="title"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

if you try to test this url: [http://www.recorramisiones.com.ar/api/get_post/? json=get_post&dev=1&p=934](http://www.recorramisiones.com.ar/api/get_post/?%20json=get_post&dev=1&p=934)

works fine. But when i test app.html just appear "Hello World" and nothing more. Any idea?

Comment: Somebody with any idea? thx

Answer (score 0):

Try add contents id like this to the html:

```
<div id="contents"></div>
</div>
```